# how to determine the impact of an running application on system load average due to CPU resource usage?

Tags: linux, performance, resources

As of my knowledge Linux system load average is affected by any means that can affect the system like CPU resource usage, memory consumption, disk I/O, network I/O etc. In top command I am checking the impact of running a python program on the system.

```
PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
13895 ayush 20 0 61.1m 12.6m 6.1m 2.9 0.2 0:06.92 python sys_stat_monitor.py
```

So it is showing the program has utilized only 2.9% of the CPU time assigned by the CPU to the program to complete its execution. So should I assume this application affected the system by 2.9% in terms of CPU resource consumption at that particular moment??

Comment: you have all information of application in /proc/<PID> of father process/*    & then you can compare things to general load & I/O

Comment: yes, but I want to know in a single core processor if an application is showing 2.9% CPU utilization, then what was the impact of this 2.9% on the total load of system at that moment? Do I need to find all the attributes which can affect the system load and find the percentage of impact due to each attribute?